# Assigning NSNumber to NSString

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSString *string = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
 int var = [string intValue];
```

var will be 2.
So, why? I understand, that it's smth about dynamic typing, but what's under the hood?

Comment: I don't see any casting.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: There is a type casting. But it is implicit. From id to NSString*. But, of course, he wanted to say something different.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, that is not casting, that is dynamic typing.

Comment: Changed question name, to avoid misunderstanding with casting/typing

Comment: No, dynamic typing refers to the objects. id and NSString* refers to pointers to objects. An object pointer with the type id has another type as an object pointer with the type NSString*. This has nothing to do with dynamic typing. Dynamic typing is done at runtime. Pointer casting is done compile time. (Usually by doing nothing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no casting going on in this code example: `[string intValue]` is a regular Objective C method provided by `NSNumber` to retrieve the value stored inside as an integer. The fact that you assigned the object to `NSString` pointer does not change anything: the object inside remains `NSNumber`. You do not get a crash because Objective C is a dynamically typed language. It lets you assign objects of wrong types, but if you try calling methods of `NSString` on your `string` object, you are going to get a crash:

```
NSString *string = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
int var = [string intValue];                // OK
BOOL isTwo = [string isEqualToString:@"2"]; // Crash
```

Comment: I think OP thinks that because he assigned his `NSNumber` object to an `NSString *` variable that there's a string somewhere in there.

Comment: Yes, the main question is why that code works? NSNumber was assigned to NSString, and then intValue converted that string in int.

Comment: @alex The NSNumber object was assigned to a pointer variable that happens to be an `NSString` pointer but the assigned object is still an `NSNumber`. No conversion is done. When you call `intValue`, it is being called on the `NSNumber` object. No strings of any kind are involved.

Comment: @alex, the question is why you ignore the warning.

Comment: @alex Hmmm. It looks real to me. :)  This is actually a great example of how Objective-C deals with object messaging. Variable types are meaningless at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `[string intValue]` is really a [message expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html).  This works since `string` is really pointing to a `NSNumber` object and it responds to the `intValue` message.  If you tried to send a message that is specific to the NSString class like `rangeOfString` you will get a "does not recognize selector" error.

If you run this in the debugger and put a breakpoint in there you will see that the runtime knows the type of `string` is really a `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

there's no typecasting its just storing a reference of `NSNumber` and then later converting it back. u dont even need a `NSString` this will work with `id`

```
id this = [NSNumber numberWithInt:22];
    int val = [this intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",val);
```